# "This App is blocked" even after getting verified from Google for restricted scope APIs in react-native

Tags: android, react-native, google-api, google-fit

I have recently got verified from Google for Google fit android APIs to read and write activity, But we are still getting that "This App is Blocked" alert while accessing the APIs, We have asked to white list one of our developer mail for testing, for only that account we are getting access. We have written to google team about this issue but no use from their reply.

How do I solve this?

Comment: related?: https://github.com/cph-cachet/flutter-plugins/issues/856